# Time is not evaluated in preg_replace output

Tags: php, date, time, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I wrote a code that converts the date format using preg_replace. It's the following code:

```
$pattern=array(
    "#Y#",//full year
    "#y#",//short year

    "#M#",//month short name
    "#F#",//month full name
    "#m#",//month number 0 lead
    "#n#",//month number
    "#t#",//days in month

    "#l#",//full week day
    "#D#",//short week day

    "#d#",//day number of month
    "#j#",//day number of month

    "#a#",//AM/PM short view
    "#A#",//AM/PM full view
            );
$replace=array(
    $d->ENnum2FA($converted[0]),//year 13xx
    $d->ENnum2FA(substr($converted[0],2),true),//year xx lead zero

    $d->shmonths[$converted[1]],//month name
    $d->months[$converted[1]],//month name
    $d->ENnum2FA($converted[1],true), //month number
    $d->ENnum2FA($converted[1]), //month number
    //$converted[1],
    $d->j_days_in_month[$converted[1]],

    $d->days[strtolower(gmdate("D",$stamp))],//week day {full view}
    $d->ldays[strtolower(gmdate("D",$stamp))],//week day ‍‍{short view}

    $d->ENnum2FA($converted[2],true),//day of month
    $d->ENnum2FA($converted[2],true),//day of month

    $d->pmam[gmdate('a',$stamp)],
    $d->pmam[gmdate('A',$stamp)],

    );
// $format = "Y/m/d"; example
$date= preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$format);
```

It changes the date format perfectly ,but the problem is that it outputs the time as **H:i:s** instead of the time value!
For example the output is **1398/5/21, H:i:s** instead of **1398/5/21, 22:15:36**.
So, I added the following code:

```
$time_f = preg_replace_callback(
    "#([His])#",
    function ($matches) {
        return(gmdate($matches[1],$stamp));
    },
    $date
);
```

It solved the problem. But Now it shows the time always as: 00:00:00
For example: **1398/5/21, 00:00:00**

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why would you expect anything to be evaluated in `preg_replace()`? That's the whole reason for `preg_replace_callback()` -- it allows you to execute code instead of using fixed replacements.

Comment: Where do you set `$stamp`?

Comment: Why don't you add `#H#`, `#i#`, and `#s#` to the `$pattern` array and do them similarly to the date?

Comment: You haven't shown any input, but why not just https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `preg_replace_callback()` function you're using the undefined local variable `$stamp`. If you need to inherit this variable from the outer scope, you need to use the `use()` option.

```
$time_f = preg_replace_callback(
    "#([His])#",
    function ($matches) use ($stamp) {
        return(gmdate($matches[1],$stamp));
    },
    $date
);
```